# ABAP ADT prerequisites?

Tags: abap, abap-adt

What do i need for setting up a connection to a local database in Eclipse to start developing in ABAP? I already installed the plugin for ABAP but i can't connect to a database. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your ABAP system at least 703 SP4?

Comment: I think it is, how do i check it?

Comment: [ABAP Development Tools (ADT)](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#abap) is an add-on to Eclipse to develop in ABAP, but it's only the frontend software, it requires another software, the "backend" (also called the ABAP-based system). Did someone give you the credentials to an existing ABAP-based system, or did you install your own free trial system ([SAP NetWeaver AS ABAP Developer Edition](https://developers.sap.com/trials-downloads.html)) or [cloud-based ABAP non-free trial system](https://www.sap.com/products/cloud-platform.html)?

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. So i need this NetWeaver on my computer to get started?

Comment: I have converted my comment into an answer, with the requested precision added at the end.

Answer (score 1):

[ABAP Development Tools (ADT)](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#abap) is an add-on to Eclipse to develop in ABAP, but it's only the frontend software, it requires another software, the "backend" (also called the ABAP-based system).

Did someone give you the credentials to an existing ABAP-based system, or did you install your own free trial system ([SAP NetWeaver AS ABAP Developer Edition](https://developers.sap.com/trials-downloads.html)) or did you subscribe to a [cloud-based ABAP non-free trial system](https://www.sap.com/products/cloud-platform.html)?

If you have none of these three systems, then I recommend that you install the free version on your laptop, for instance the latest [7.52 SP04 version](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/10/01/as-abap-7.52-sp04-developer-edition-concise-installation-guide/).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other development scenarios,  ABAP development requires a backend repository.
Without an SAP Netweaver Stack (ABAP server) there is no repository.

The ABAP repository is where:

- ABAP code is stored,
- ABAP code is compiled
- and where code is executed.

Eclipse is the only the IDE and it is constantly communicating with the ABAP server.

Answer (score 1):

ADT works through RFC connection and requires some ICF services to be enabled on backend. Did you make [some necessary configurations](https://help.sap.com/doc/2e65ad9a26c84878b1413009f8ac07c3/201909.000/en-US/config_guide_system_backend_abap_development_tools.pdf) in backend? alike:

- profile paramethers
- S_ADT_RES, S_RFC authorizations
- `docu`, `toolsdocu` ICF services

Answer (score 1):

You can create a free tier trial account with SAP BTP. Create an ABAP environment (Free trial) then connect it to Eclipse so you will have a backend system in SAP BTP.