# How to create a new ABAP project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, abap, hana

I recently installed Eclipse 06-2019 and the ABAP tools for development. When I want to make a new project I get this error:

> Problem Occurred: Location 'C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common' does not point to a SAP GUI configuration file. See 'Details' for more information.

[image: Error]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe your question is irrelevant if you don't have an ABAP backend connected, cf [my comment in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285195/abap-developing-in-eclipse).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of text errors are not searchable, nor are they accessible. Please [edit] the question to augment the image with the text that it contains.

Comment: What have you already done, and what do you want to achieve?

Do you have a NW backend available? Do you have SAP GUI installed?

Creating a "new project" in ADT (Eclipse) simply means connecting to a SAP backend.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install SAP GUI and working server info on it. Eclipse will run GUI in background and get information from it.

Comment: Actually no, SAPGui [is not required](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#abap) for working with ABAP in Cloud on ADT and since OP tagged question as HANA he is intended to work with cloud and maybe with no ABAP at all. Connection configurations can be setup without SAPGui.