# Logon to system DEV failed (System DEV does not support Eclipse based ABAP Development Tools)

Tags: abap, abap-adt

I get that error:

> Logon to system DEV failed (System DEV does not support Eclipse based ABAP Development Tools)

I have the credentials to the SAP system and I have already setup ABAP in Eclipse. But whenever I try to logon I get that error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ABAP ADT prerequisites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285195/abap-adt-prerequisites)

Answer (score 3):

There are also a couple steps which need to be done in the backend system in order to allow connections from Eclipse. There is a guide [Configuring the ABAP Back-end for ABAP Development Tools](https://help.sap.com/doc/2e65ad9a26c84878b1413009f8ac07c3/201909.001/en-US/config_guide_system_backend_abap_development_tools.pdf) on help.sap.com which outlines all the steps.

But the tl;dr is:

- The SAP NetWeaver version must support ADT. The lowest version is 7.3 EHP 1, but some higher versions might also require a certain Service Pack. See the document linked above for the complete list.
- The developers using Eclipse need the roles `SAP_BC_DWB_ABAPDEVELOPER` and `SAP_BC_DWB_WBDISPLAY` (or roles with equivalent permissions). You can assign roles with transaction `SU01`.
- The following ICF services need to be enabled in transaction `SICF`:

  - default_host > sap > public > bc > abap > docu
  - default_host > sap > public > bc > abap > toolsdocu
  - default_host > sap > bc > abap > docu
  - default_host > sap > bc > abap > toolsdocu
  - default_host > sap > bc > adt
  - default_host > sap > bc > webdynpro > sap
- The following system profile parameters need to be set in transaction `RZ11`:

  - login/create_sso2_ticket = 3
  - login/accept_sso2_ticket = 1